# Maximum height reached by an object

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, velocity, escape-velocity

[image]

Here, in the last line, from the formula  s is negative, but how can s be negative?
Also, should it not be s=u^2/2g instead of
s= - u^2/2g?

Comment: It's easy to make sign errors like that. It's unfortunate that it's in a textbook. Maybe write to the author or publisher. At least tell your teacher about it.

Comment: Another interpretation: the author considered the value of $g$ to be positive, he considered the up direction to be positive, and the negative sign indicates that the gravitational force is down and the direction of the object's motion is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, in the last line, from the formula  s is negative, but how can s be negative?

It's a typo.

> Also, should it not be s=u^2/2g instead of
> s= - u^2/2g?

Yes.

Comment: As @davidwhite explained, they are considering downward acceleration as being negative, by using a=-g. That assumption means that the equations are correct.

Comment: No, the equations are not correct, and that is not what @davidwhite "explained."  The value of g is +9.8m/s/s. The value of a is -9.8m/s/s. The value of u^2 is positive. The value of -u^2/2g is negative. The value of u^2/2g is positive.